# How do I detect when a shulker box is opened?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So basically, I want to create a way to detect when a shulker box is opened, using commands. I've searched everywhere on the internet on how to do so, and I can't find an answer.

Comment: Could you please elaborate so as to what you have already tried doing, also if an answer helps you, don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You first should add a scoreboard that increases whenever you open a shulker, you can do so like this:

```
scoreboard objectives add shulker minecraft.custom:minecraft.open_shulker_box
```

Then, in a repeating command block, or in a `tick.mcfunction` file, you can put this:

```
execute as @a[scores={shulker=1..}] at @s run (your command)
```

And now, so the command only executes once, you can do (also in a repeating command block/`tick.mcfunction` file):

```
scoreboard players reset @a[scores={shulker=1..}] shulker
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scoreboard objectives add opened_shulker minecraft.custom:minecraft.open_shulker_box
```

All players who open a shulker box will have `1` added to their score.